Forward username on apache reverse proxy with basic auth
I have a reverse proxy (packages) which forward request to another website (localhost) with a basic auth using a file. For debug purpose, I would need to get the username in the log of the localhost website but it is empty.
Here is the configuration of my reverse-proxy:
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass        "http://localhost:80/" timeout=30
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:80/"

    AuthType basic
    AuthBasicProvider file

    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/packages.htpasswd

    Require valid-user
</Location>

In the logs of the proxy, I correctly see the user (titou) who tries to login
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - titou [30/Sep/2024:17:04:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 4233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

but in the logs of the "actual" website, the information is lost. Is it possible to forward only the username? (I do not need the password)
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024:16:50:54 +0000] "GET /icons/openlogo-75.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6040 "https://packages.XXXX.com/" 

I've tried to use the rewritecond module but without success
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=ENV_REMOTE_USER:%1]
    RequestHeader set X-REMOTE-USER %{ENV_REMOTE_USER}e

